# What is kcjlogger on Kyocera phones?

Tags: stock-android, malware

I have a Kyocera Hydro. There is a directory on the phone kcjlogger. It sounds suspicious. Does anyone know what it is or how I can investigate to find out? I was unable to find any answers searching. Thanks

```
shell@android:/data/kcjlogger/tmp # ls -al
ls -al
-rw------- system   system          0 2015-04-15 22:38 kcjlog_from_tombstone_00
```

Comment: Could you try to open the file using text editor and see what its content? Researching that didn't return any useful info. It could actually be KCJ Logger, and not "keylogger", but researching that returned nothing either.

Comment: @Andrew the file is size 0 it has no content unfortunately.